# Proving an identity in linear algebra involving dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some trouble understanding a certain proof in a linear algebra textbook. Essentially, we have a subspace $V$ $\subset R^n$ with an orthonormal basis ${\{u_1, u_2, ..., u_k\}}$.

Then, given a vector $v \in R^n$, we can express the vector as $v = (v \cdot u_1)u_1 + (v \cdot u_2)u_2 + ... + (v \cdot u_k) u_k$.

However, in the next line of the proof, it is written that $v = u_1 u_1^Tv + u_2 u_2^T v + ... + u_k u_k^Tv$.

It is then noted that $u_1 u_1^T + u_2 u_2^T + ... + u_k u_k^T$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and so, this is the projection matrix for the projection of $v$ onto the subspace $V$.

I am not able to understand how $(v \cdot u_1)u_1$ can be written as $u_1 u_1^Tv$. I know that the dot product of two vectors $a \cdot b$ can be written as a matrix multiplication $a^T b$ but this fact alone won't allow us to go from $(v \cdot u_1)u_1$ to $u_1 u_1^Tv$.

Comment: $u_1u_1^Tv=(u_1^Tv)u_1$

Comment: @AndrewZhang With what I know, I have only managed to write the following $(v \cdot u_1) u_1 = (u_1 \cdot  v) u_1 = (u_1^T  v) u_1$

Comment: @AndrewZhang What you have suggested seems to be the crucial next step. But how do you prove that it is true?

Comment: Hint: in [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) a column vector $w$ satisfies$$[(v\cdot w)w]_i=v_kw_kw_i=(ww^T)_{ik}v_k=(ww^Tv)_i.$$

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for your help! I understand what is the summation notation you are using. But the 2nd part to the 3rd part of the equality is still a jump for me... Will think about it

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but the point here is that if $a$ is a scalar and $x$ a vector then $ax=xa$

Comment: @AndrewZhang Oh your point is that $(u_1^T v)$ is a scalar and $u_1$ is a vector. So then, $(u_1^T v) u_1 = u_1 (u_1^T v)$?